# Set variable to equal contents of div

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, dom, console

```
<div class="detail">Upgrade Level 4</div>
```

I have a `div` in my website that is the same as the above. I have set a variable to equal this `div` using the code :

```
tavern = document.querySelector(".detail")
```

I now want a new variable to equal the number inside this `div`. So I need a way to filter out the "Upgrade Level" and set a new variable to equal the number inside the `div` :

```
tavernLevel = 4
```

Im not to sure how to do this?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You could use **[`split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split)** function if the text in always the same `Upgrade Level "number"` it will splits a String object into an array of strings by separating the string into substrings using given separator (in our case separator is `Upgrade Level`) so it will return array of two columns `['Upgrade Level ','4']` and we will take the second column using the index `[1]`:

```
var tavern = document.querySelector(".detail").innerText;
var tavernLevel = tavern.split('Upgrade Level ')[1];
```

Hope this helps.

```js
var tavern = document.querySelector(".detail").innerText;
var tavernLevel = tavern.split('Upgrade Level ')[1];

alert(tavernLevel);
```

```html
<div class="detail">Upgrade Level 4</div>
```

Comment: when i run this in the chrome console it returns undefined do you know why this may be

Comment: @A.Seidel it return an alert with undefined value inside it? works fine in my chrome check this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/jnwrc5ay/123/

Comment: @ZakariaAcharki the error came from a lower case "L" for level thanks for the help ive got it working now https://jsfiddle.net/Adamseidel/c44eanzw/3/

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with regular expression.

```
var regExp = /\d+/g;

var strHtml = "Upgrade level 4";

strHtml.match(regExp ); // return ["4"].Just use parseInt to get the number
```